# ASP.NET Core 2.1 unable to cast IServiceProvider

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, service-provider

My application ASP.net web API project on core 2.1

I have the following IOC container class

```
// Ioc.cs
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Rendigo.Core.Data;

public static class Ioc
{  
    public static RendigoContext RendigoContext => 
    IocContainer.Provider.GetService<RendigoContext>();
}

// IocContainer.cs
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

public static class IocContainer
{
    public static ServiceProvider Provider { get; set; }
}

//startup.cs 


  public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, 
                    IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        // exception is raised here 
        IocContainer.Provider = (ServiceProvider)serviceProvider;
         var context = Ioc.RendigoContext;
    // .....
    }
```

The exception detail

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope' to type 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider'.'

- I used this approach with ASP core 2.0 and it was working fine.
- I have 2 questions on this:

  1. Why I am getting this exception am I missing some code to place in program.cs
     or a library needs to be imported via nuget.
  2. Is this approach of making the context static is a good approach to follow.

Comment: the error message tells you exactly what is the problem. The inject provider is of type `ServiceProviderEngineScope` but you are trying to cast it to `ServiceProvider`

Comment: You're abstracting a service that is already abstracted.  Worse still you're making the whole thing static.  The DI framework in .NET Core can handle all your service provisioning needs.  I suggest reading the docs to learn the fundamentals of DI https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. why i am getting this exception am i missing some code to place in program.cs or a library needs to be imported via nuget.

The error message tells you exactly what is the problem. The injected provider is of type `ServiceProviderEngineScope` but you are trying to cast it to `ServiceProvider`

> 2. is this approach of making the context static is a good approach to follow

**No.**

You are basically creating a service locator, which is considered more of an anti-pattern. There should be no need to pass around the `IServiceProvider` as that should be the first indication of a code smell. It is advised you review your current design choices.

Consider practicing [Explicit Dependency Principle](https://deviq.com/explicit-dependencies-principle/)

> Methods and classes should explicitly require (typically through method parameters or constructor parameters) any collaborating objects they need in order to function correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem like this:

```
IoCContainer.Provider = serviceProvider as ServiceProvider;
```

Comment: **Warning:** The documentation states "If the conversion is not possible, the **as** operator returns null. Unlike the cast operator **()**, the **as** operator never throws an exception.". This says to me that your "solution" hides the problem and doesn't actually solve it. You end up with a `null` instead of an exception, which could just throw a null exception later on.

Answer (score -1):

IocContainer.Provider =(ServiceProvider) app.ApplicationServices;

hope this help...